# How to deal with change in diet and schedule after returning from a long expedition?

Tags: mountaineering

Before going to the expedition lately, I did have a very odd schedule with eating and sleeping habits. I would have dinner at about 11 pm and sleep at about 1 am, which is very bad for a mountaineer. Through the expedition I struggled immensely due to these habits. But, we did have a strict eating and sleeping schedule when we were through the expedition, and that was for more than 15 days. For certain obvious reasons I didn't eat much in quantity being at higher grounds.

Now, I am back to routine, office and late working nights, I can hardly digest anything that I eat through the day. I would wake up at about 3 am for no reason and stay up. That makes me go crazy as the day progresses, and yet I (have to) work late.

Have anybody ever had such an issue after an expedition?

Comment: Are you getting enough exercise?

Comment: How many time zones were you away from your place of residence?

Comment: @ab2: Sorry for the delayed response, I am getting exercise, but not as much as I did before going to the expedition.

Comment: @KenGraham: Sorry for the delayed response, I was in the same time zone. I am from India and the expedition was in Indian part of Himalayan ranges.

Comment: This has to be bordering on medical seeking advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *a lot* to consider. I go on long canoe sailing trips and eating is basically when we can on the go and one solid meal at the camp. Yours is more lifestyle  changes. Some of us are up and down with the sun others with the moon. When you find out what you are naturally then it will come together. Here's a simple plan: eat when you're hungry and stop when you're not. And at some point you will fast when you sleep.
Yes I have had similar problems. Hope this helps buddy.